# How to refresh a previous fragment on back press without disturbing the back stack

Tags: android

I am using one activity for tabactivity with viewpager and attached fragmentA.when i want to move fragmentB ,replaced fragmentB with present fragmentA.I need to find solution for onbackpress in FragmentB refresh fragmentA wihtout changing Backstack because i used nearly ten fragments in one tab.

Is there any method in fragment life cycle

Comment: can you elaborate in detail because this question is not clear to me.

Comment: in my application i used one activity  added a fragment with  three tabs ,on first tab replaced nearly five fragments when i am in 5th fragment i want to refresh 4th fragment  without changing back stack because when we back press on 4th  fragment it shouls redirect to 3rd fragment

in my above question i mentioned  parent as activity but  it is one activity and then i added a fragment with three tabs

Comment: i need to handle onbackpress in fragment

Comment: so you want to track the back press and which fragment is opened when the back button is pressed, right? I think If you can achieve that, you can refresh the particular fragment. Or is it about just refreshing the 4th fragment when it is re-opened when someone clicks back button on 5th fragment?

Answer (score 6):

When Fragment B over Fragment A, fragment A is onPause(). After backpress, fragment A is onResume(). So you can create a boolean to observe this change.

In Fragment A

```
private boolean isBackFromB;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isBackFromB=false;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isBackFromB = true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
    if (isBackFromB) //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working very well for my fragment from view pager

Answer (score 0):

override `onBackPressed()` method in `Activity`, add all `fragment` in backstack.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

FragmentManager manager =getFragmentManager();
int count = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();

if (count == 0) {
    super.onBackPressed();
  } else {
    manager.popBackStack();
  }

}
```

Comment: @Emzoz can you plase give hint how to add fragment in backstack on onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

View pager does not always hold it's fragments in memory, so you have to handle 2 scenarios:
1 - fragment is recreated - just read data from wherever you hold them and show in ordinary way.
2 - fragment is modified from outside while still has been held by ViewPager, and as I understand this is what concerns you.
What you can do is to create this [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and then notify fragment that it was shown again and possibly should reload it's data.

More complex answer for communicating between different application's components is using some event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).